# Can't use ./create in Terminal Phonegap

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

i've been trying and researching this all day and still can't seem to find an answer.

I'm trying to create an android package with phonegap on my desktop but keep getting the error 'An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1'

I have no idea what's wrong, im using a fresh file path.  I've also tried all of the other solutions out there but i still can't seem to create the project!

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you type the command `which android` you will probably see that android is not in your path so you what you want to do is a do `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android/platform-tools:/path/to/android/tools` now you when you type `which android` you should see /path/to/android  hope this helps